# $\pi + e$ is irrational, I want to share but nervous.

Tags: discussion, soft-question

I have the proof for $\pi + e$ being irrational.

Honestly, I’ve been delving into irrational analysis for awhile now, and I got lucky stumbling into a solution. I’m not an amateur mathematician, but credentially-bottom. Would love to share because I know its interesting, but is this a good place to offer an argument?

Comment: Asking whether an argument you have is correct may be a reasonable question to post here.

Comment: Or you could upload a preprint to arxiv(dot)org. $\qquad$

Comment: Let's see your proof, you can answer the question

Comment: IMO, this is not really a good place for that. Have a math instructor/professor you know talk with you about it; maybe you're right and can get it published. But to be honest a lot of people come to MSE with posts in the vein of "I have proved/disproved [longstanding open conjecture/problem]," and it gets a bit tiresome. (A lot of the time these often tend to be the same copy-and-paste proof someone found online, or they are often severely lacking in one or more respects.) 

(cont.)

Comment: Or at least, that's usually when you as an amateur are assuming you're right to begin with. A healthy level of skepticism and tempering of one's expectations should be encouraged. Now, if you want people to look over your alleged proof for possible flaws (rather than just to share your alleged proof), MSE will be open to that -- just be sure to take the criticism in stride if and when it comes, rather than stalwartly assuming you're right.

Comment: @EeveeTrainer how would you get it published, if it's true

Comment: Thank you everyone here for all the kind help. I’ll see what steps I can take after typing it up in LaTeX before wonderful skeptics such as you all can have a chance to reason against it.

Comment: If its multiple pages long then you are probably better off putting it in arxiv and/or sending to a journal IMO

Comment: There is a relevant question on main [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/898042/10513), about what to do with a proof of an open problem.

Comment: You should post it here. Some people with grumble but plenty of people will enjoy taking a look. Eventually if it's not worthy of attention, it will be downvoted and fall out of sight which is no inconvenience to anybody.

Comment: If it's long you might do better to just include core arguments and referrence the whole proof, otherwise you should be fine (+ with above suggestions of course, especially ackwnoledging that you are aware the proof might have an error (and most likely does) should help to get better response - after all there is probably a good reason these problems have been unsolved for such a long time...)

Comment: A purported proof of Goldbach's conjecture currently stands like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4070134/are-there-any-issues-with-this-proof-of-goldbach-s-conjecture) on our site. You may read the comments below it and make conclusions.

Comment: I'd suggest, for a positive response, that people on chat can help you, say the Mathematics chat room. Alternately, you can ask about a sub-argument with appropriate context. As you can see, what doesn't work is posting the whole argument, because it's very unlikely that there will be an *elementary* proof of less than a page's length.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon the link you put in one of your comments doesn't work, the page has been deleted.

Comment: If you do share it, make sure you take measures to make sure no-one 'steals' your proof, as this problem, from what I've read, is one of 'the great mathematical problems'; I'm sure you want to be credited for solving it! :)

Comment: @A-LevelStudent Oh, ok, thanks ! Although that sends a message by itself : the question was not received well. The gist is a user posting a complete elementary "proof" of the Goldbach conjecture that was the length of just $1$ page, not typed in MathJax but rather in LaTeX and added via an image, and then asking for review.  I am happy , though, at your encouragement of the OP posting their proof. I am with this if it is done correctly, although I have outlined steps that will lead to better reception.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon thanks for the clarification. To be honest, I'm incredibly excited to think that the proof for this problem may be shared here! (Although I probably won't understand one jot of it :) )

Comment: @A-LevelStudent You should probably be aware that some real big names  in math frequent the website. It's not like they all sit on MO, I know some real big shots here. You may call yourself an A-Level student, but you have an account on MSE, so in no time you will be a super star student! I've had conversations with people here that I could never have thought I'd meet in real life.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon I didn't know that, I thought all the 'big shots' were on MO! Then again, I probably don't know enough mathematicians to recognise them if I would see their name. That's really cool (btw in case you didn;t realize my name isn't a reference to my abilities ;) )

Comment: @A-LevelStudent Ah , of course I should have guessed! (Regarding your name) Yes, you can take my word for it, there are some well-respected mathematicians here on MSE as well! It is not necessary that they have high reputation, but they have valuable contributions.

Comment: @A-LevelStudent: publishing any content on any public forum will ensure that any actions of plagiarism can be handled if it comes to notice. This is simply because users in general don't have access to modify time when a content was published. Don't worry about it.

Comment: for @A-LevelStudent and other sub10K rep users perhaps in the future, here is the prior content of the now deleted page as screenshots https://imgur.com/a/6ZNwB0t

Comment: Don’t fret, share it!

Comment: For any $\lambda$ whatsoever is $\pi + \lambda e$ rational?

Comment: @Aruralreader $\lambda = \frac{-e}{\pi}$? But you can try the following simpler exercise : either $\pi + e$ is irrational or $\pi e$ is irrational (hint : Vieta's formula) and see if you can extend this logic to $\pi + \lambda e$ for $\lambda$ rational. It gives an either/or statement which is very useful.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon does that mean that it can't be that both are irrational?

Comment: @A-LevelStudent It could be that both are irrational (in fact, one would think it likely from an amateur point of view that both are), but it can't be that both are rational. This kind of either/or stuff is really useful, because it increases the number of approaches you can have to the same problem.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon from your hint, I've thought of a possible proof: consider the expression $(x-e)(x-\pi)$. Since $e$ and $\pi$ are both transcendental, at least some of the coefficients of this polynomial must be irrational; hence at least one of $\pi+e$ and $\pi e$ is irrational. Is that right?

Comment: @TeresaLisbon thank you!

Comment: @A-LevelStudent You are welcome!

Comment: If you do end up publishing it in another medium, please leave a link here. A lot of us are curious to see what the proof consists of.

Comment: Does a magician disclose his or her magic tricks?

Comment: Quick update: I am running the document past some peers and going through a few drafts to make sure the argument is as clear and concise as possible. I sincerely appreciate everyone's advice on the matter and just want to make sure that if there is an error I am missing, it is easy to find.

Comment: @AceSarich Any news?

Comment: @A-LevelStudent He had a truly marvellous proof, but, the character limit prevented him from writing it.

Comment: @Buraian Nice one :-) Maybe this is a job for Andrew Wiles? :-)

Comment: @A-LevelStudent: Of course not. It's just like waiting for news of a proof that PA is inconsistent.

Comment: @A-LevelStudent I constructed a discussion and philosophy oriented paper on ViXra which can be found at vixra.org/pdf/2108.0091v1.pdf I at best wanted to document the frame of reference which led me to believe a strong proof was achievable through non-rigorous analysis. If anyone reads this maybe it will help somebody beat me to an elegant solution. Otherwise, from the time of my last response, I must confess that without a formula, my “proof” is no more than a consequence of belief in a certain arbitrary set of axioms. Which essentially as of today means no news. I.e. still a good problem.

Answer (score 65):

No, this is not the correct place to post your solution. At best this looks like self-righteous advertising, at worst spam.

There are a few caveats and points for discussion here though.

1. This is a Q&A site. Saying "here is my proof" is not a question...
2. The problem of determining if $\pi+e$ is irrational is stated on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irrational_number#Open_questions) as being open, and so you should read the question [What should an amateur do with a proof of an open problem?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/898042/10513)
   .
3. If the problem you solved were not Wikipedia-famous then my answer might be different.
4. An acceptable question **might** be something like: *"I was thinking about this problem and got lucky stumbling into what looks like a solution. I cannot find an error in it. However, as the proof is so short and elementary I was wondering if any of you could find the error? Thanks."* This is a question (so addresses (1)), and shows that you are sceptical of your result*.

*Half of maths is being sceptical, including of your own proofs and also of those in papers by fancy people published in fancy journals.

Comment: You should add that people in chatrooms might be interested to discuss this, and I don't think they will ask to be very specific. In fact, the mathematics chatroom will be able to reply very quickly to the proof, I'd think!

Comment: Objecting on the basis that an already-written proof is not a question is silly. There is an ‘answer your own question’ checkbox when asking a new question, and it’s pretty easy to phrase the problem in the form of a separate question and answer. Now, whether the proof is *correct* is another matter…

Comment: @user3840170 So then the "question" would be the famous problem, and the "answer" would be a(n attempted) proof? That doesn't make a lot of sense, since a famous problem would make a poor question post, and an the attempted proof posted as an answer doesn't really facilitate trying to get feedback on the proof.

Comment: @user3840170 That point is the least of my objections, and can be easily overcome (e.g. by phrasing it like in point 4). My main point, however, is point 2 (and none of the answers in the linked question say "post it here!").

Comment: @TeresaLisbon I think posting to chat depends on what they are hoping to get out of it. If they are just hoping for some informal feedback then chat might be OK. I think anyone posting such a solution anywhere on the internet should be thinking "Why am I posting this here? What am I hoping to get out of this?". A lot of the answers to the [question I linked to](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/898092/) suggest posting on the arXiv, but why? What's the point? It's not a magical place where arXiv papers are automatically accepted by the community.

Comment: (Also, regarding this question, I agree strongly with [Did's comments](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/898042/what-should-an-amateur-do-with-a-proof-of-an-open-problem/898092#comment1853695_898092) there, so I feel I should highlight them.)

Comment: @user1729 In agreement with your comments, I just felt that if the user wanted to do something with this site and that proof, then chat is consultable. Of course, it is highly informal, but the people who are there are qualified enough to say something useful.

Comment: @user1729: _what's the point?_ Well, sharing such a marvelous piece of proof to everyone itself is the most important point. Any professional benefit including fame and money pales in comparison to that. Who knows there might be another Apery moment.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh My question is not "what is the point of sharing it?" but instead "what's the point of sharing it *there*?" (specifically the arXiv, but also on Math.SE or anywhere else). Anyone in such a situation should be considering the most effective way to distribute their proof. I hold opinions on this matter (posting it on the arXiv, viXra or here would be ineffective, while journal system is designed precisely for this purpose) but my *point* is that anyone in this situation should consider this question (and possible ignore my opinion).

Comment: @user1729: oh I understood your intent. Unless the motive is related to professional benefit, I think mathse has a wider outreach. Just share it with any of the academia persons whom you respect here (via chat) and such a thing like irrationality of $\pi+e$ will get viral in minutes.

Comment: @user1729: well the reach of mathse extends way beyond typical paid journals precisely because it is free. I just don't like mathematical knowledge to be paid.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh
One major issue with posting the proof here is that proofs need to be "stamped" for correctness, which again journals give you. It is only then that viral-ness should happen. (In the 90s a well-respected professor submitted a proof of the Poincaré conjecture, and his uni's publicity department got wind of this and advertised it heavily...and then someone found an (obvious) error and everyone was embarassed for the guy.)

Comment: Regarding journals, the whole "money" thing frustrates me too. However, there are plenty of quality open access journals, such as
[Annales Henri Lebesgue](https://annales.lebesgue.fr/index.php/AHL/),
[Discrete Analysis](https://discreteanalysisjournal.com/),
[Documenta Mathematica](https://www.elibm.org/series?q=se:2204),
[Münster Journal of Mathematics](https://www.uni-muenster.de/FB10/mjm/),
and
[New York Journal of Mathematics](http://nyjm.albany.edu/).

Comment: @user1729: I don't think one should post a complicated proof here to get it verified by experts. But if it is self contained and matches length of typical posts here. I see no problem. Many users will happily verify it and give the stamp of approval. The journal system uses similar people in editorial boards to verify results. Moreover the best is that the proof is self explanatory that it can be understood without help of experts.

Comment: I object to the phrasing "Half of maths is being skeptical, including of your own proofs and also of those in papers by fancy people published in fancy journals." I would say half of maths (maybe more or less, not sure the %) is _verifying_ (which also helps in ingesting material). The difference being that "I have not verified X" or "I tried to verify X but there is a flaw in the proof" is a lot different from "I doubt X" or "I don't expect anyone outside a certain circle to prove X". Verification is objective and rigorous, skepticism is sociological and lazy.

Comment: @John_Krampf saying "half of maths is verification" implies that I spend half my time verifying other peoples proofs. This is not true. My point was really about having a mental state of not believing things based on who wrote them (including if it was yourself) or where it was published. It's not saying "I doubt X" to other people, but instead being aware that mistakes are easy to make by anyone, and result should not be judged superficially.

Comment: @user1729: while working on famous/open problems, it makes sense to be skeptical. After all there were some gaps in Wiles proof too which he fixed later. I once saw a paper which erroneously extended Beukers proof for irrationality of $\zeta(3)$ to $\zeta(5)$. So in the midst of any excitement of working on an open problem one should not go overboard and restrain oneself a little.

Comment: And there is the other side of the story. When everyone was thinking that "primes is in P" was a damn difficult open problem, AKS came up with a very smart simple proof.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Had the pleasure of seeing Nitin Saxena in a seminar. A real gentleman, but let's say when the mathematics audience tried to make sense of his computer scientific notations and notions, he could not help them over the line, so half his talk was a little blurred to some people. But otherwise, fine talk it was.

Comment: @user1729: Recently Lisa Hayden has attempted to prove the Riemann Hypothesis, and posted about it [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4172709/riemann-hypothesis-a-probably-wrong-proof-but-where-is-the-mistake). Unfortunately, despite the great amount of effort she devoted to this attempted proof, her post only served to demonstrate that attempted proofs of open problems just aren't very suitable for this site.

Comment: @Joe in the words of Andreas Blass, who commented on the [double-post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/395291/riemann-hypothesis-proof-where-is-the-mistake-in-this-proof#comment1011719_395291) to MathOverflow, "Alleged proofs belong on the arXiv, not on MathOverflow."

Comment: @user1729: Actually, that's not really right. Preprints belong on arXiv. Poofs of open problems belong on viXra.

Answer (score -3):

It's something that users have posted here before (an incorrect proof that $\pi + e$ is irrational).

If you have a correct proof, you could give it as a new Answer to [Proof of $\pi$ + $e$ irrational](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/507032/proof-of-pie-irrational).  But you should do the research and check that you are not offering an incorrect proof much like the attempts that have been posted here previously.

**The older post was closed, reopened, reclosed, and deleted**

Apparently the exposure of that Question here on meta inspired a group of close votes a few hours ago.  It had been asked and answered seven and a half years ago, so the timing suggests cause-and-effect.

Comment: I would hope that the OP's proof is incomparably better than the "proof" given at your link! It would be a mistake to post it there as an answer, in my opinion.

Comment: For my numerous down voters, I'd point out that my invitation to post an Answer on the main site is conditioned on "If you have a correct proof".  Although it is likely that no such proof has been stumbled upon, it is part of our mission to collect good content and help learners of mathematics at all levels.  Which of us has not learned something from their mistakes?  Some of which I've posted before having my confusion pointed out...

Comment: @hardmath: your conclusion about linked post and its closure is correct. I had seen that post long back and downvoted it but had forgotten until it came up here.

Comment: @hardmath: the question you linked is about a concrete (and very naive) attempt a person made at the question. A proof would not answer the question (and the current answer is perfect).

Comment: My downvote is actually based on the fact that, if they **do** have a correct proof, I think it is an incredibly **poor** idea to post it on MSE (as an answer to the linked post or otherwise). This is an open problem and they should work on getting it written up and published.

Comment: The older post has been reopened now.

Comment: @Joe It is deleted...

Comment: @ShiveringSoldier: After I posted my comment, it was closed again, then deleted. I have voted to undelete. I see nothing wrong with that question.

Comment: I agree. I cast my vote a few days ago, and I was surprised to find out that it remains deleted.

Comment: @ShiveringSoldier: It's sad that this meta thread has generated such controversy surrounding that question.