# Migrating a question to Meta doesn't decrease reputation

Tags: discussion, bug, reputation, migration, meta-reputation

Recently, a [question about the irrationality of $\pi + \mathrm e$](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33323/228959) got migrated from Main to Meta. While on Main, that question had obtained a total of 5 - 1 = 4 votes, for a total of 50 - 2 = 48 reputation points. Strangely, the removal of the question from Main didn't cost its author these reputation points, despite the fact that votes on Meta are not equivalent to votes on Main (the former do not alter reputation). The fact that the question got migrated indicates that it was not fit for Main, therefore I was expecting the reputation points that it had brought to vanish after migration. Is this a bug of the SE software?

Comment: Not to be crude, but who cares if someone else has some reputation that you think doesn't belong?

Comment: @LSpice: I asked the question believing that I had stumbled upon a bug in the SE software. It was not the (un-)deserved reputation that was bothering me, but the possibility of a bug.

Comment: @Glorfindel: When I composed the post, it was on purpose that I didn't include a link to that page, not willing to artificially increase its count view and (artificially) turn it into a "hot" MSE post. Notice, also, that including that link didn't improve my post in any significant way. It would be so nice if people stopped editing other peoples' posts under the claim of "improvement"!

Comment: @AlexM. it [was a hot Meta question already](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/33323/timeline), no need to worry about that. As always, if you disagree with an edit like this, feel free to roll it back.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The question [still exists on the main site](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4069111/pi-e-is-irrational-i-want-to-share-but-nervous?noredirect=1), so they keep their reputation – for now that is.

> **The question is left as a stub**, or pathway to the new site, **for 30 days**, after which it is automatically deleted by a weekly script.

(source: [What is migration and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10249/295232))

In a month or so, the question will be deleted from the main site, and then the author will lose their reputation.

Comment: Note that Qs and As are treated differently. From the same question on Meta,  

**Answers on the origin site are deleted immediately upon question migration.** (This causes a reversal of all associated reputation on the origin site.) The answers will be visible on the destination question.