# Is asking to verify my P=NP proof appropriate?

Tags: support, allowed-questions, proof-verification

Is providing link to my (8 pages) proof of P=NP and asking to check my proof appropriate for a math.SE question?

Comment: I can't believe that there are 3 users close-voting this post with the reason that this should be posted on main instead.....

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$\pi + e$ is irrational, I want to share but nervous.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33323/pi-e-is-irrational-i-want-to-share-but-nervous)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

No. It is not. This is not the purpose of this website.

Answer (score 2):

No, I'm not sure any stackexchange website would be considered appropriate for your "proof".

P = NP is considered an unsolved problem, "The problem has been called the most important open [unknown] problem in computer science."   Some of the brightest minds and PhD's in math and computer science have attempted to prove or P = NP without success.
Either your proof has a mistake, which is most likely, or you will get the equivalent of a Nobel prize in Computer Science, which is extremely unlikely.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_versus_NP_problem

At the very least consider phrasing your question- "Where is the mistake in my proof?"

Comment: This is even less appropriate on MathOverflow than here, and arguably this is also the case for the cs websites. I'm not sure what would make you say otherwise.

Comment: At least on CS or CStheory the topic would be correct.  
I have edited my answer though.